# Backbone & EVE & CORS: PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: javascript, python, cors, eve

Just started learning Backbone and EVE. Now I'm doing the Model save/restore tutorial and I'm get stuck. Details on the full application/settings.py
[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2571325/mv.zip). Note that the small html file is read locally by Chrome, so I added X_DOMAINS and X_HEADERS to settings.py to enable CORS for the EVE calls.
Created a model with three fields and save it:

```
var proj = new Project({projID: "prj2", projName: "Data", projParent: "work"})
proj.save();
```

But EVE answers:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/projects/prj2. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

But changing the save to `proj.save({}, {type: "POST"})` or `proj.save({}, {patch: true})` changes only the not allowed method. I suspect CORS blocks everything except GET, but I don't know how to fix this (or maybe CORS is only a red herring).
Thanks for looking!

Comment: I'm removing `backbone` since this is something you need to enable at your python backend. You need to add `PUT` in one of the response headers

Comment: backbone is backbone.js a javascript library.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with backbone. Your solution has to be implemented in backend by modifying response headers. But I'm not familiar with python hence I removed backbone and added python so that someone experienced in python can give you exact answer...

Comment: CORS is definitely a red herring. Now I serve the small HTML page and the required JavaScript libraries through EVE. Now the error is 405 method not allowed. Keep investigating.

Comment: Thanks TJ, seems I'm missing some EVE setting. No idea which one. Investigating.

Comment: Solved! Was Backbone that decided that my Model was not new and so used PUT on a not existing resource. All this started by copying from the tutorial `idAttribute:` pointing to one of my fields instead of `"_id"` that I think it is the default.